# Image tag inside anchor tag inside PHP eco

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, href

The following is my php code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($return_data)) {

        $id = "ID:".$row['demo_id']."<br>";
        $name = "Name: ".$row['demo_name']."<br>";
        $version = "Version: ".$row['demo_version']."<br>";
        $details = "Details: ".$row['demo_details']."<br>";
        $file = "File Link: ".$row['file']."<br>";
        $new = basename( $row['file'] ); // GET FILE NAME ONLY, GET RID OF PATH.
        '<img src = \"../demo_webpages_project/images/$new"/>';
        echo '<a href = "http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':8080/demo_webpages_project/images/".$new> Link </a>';
```

I want the 'link' to take me to the image 'file' that I uploaded.

But since I put the anchor tag inside the the echo, it assumes '.
$new' as literal instead of taking value from the $new variable.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: use `"` double quotes if you want the variable interpreted

Comment: You are just in double/single quote hell. simplify it

Comment: And that <img>` is not in the anchor, its hanging in no mans land so that code should not compile

Comment: @Ghost Hi where exactly should i use double quotes. If I use echo "<a href = 'http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":8080/demo_webpages_project/images/'.$new> Link </a>"; It takes me to the images folder

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried almost all permutations of the quotes but in vain

Comment: Have you tried `HEREDOC` or other string alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get into this sort of situation I just break things down into managable pieces like this.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($return_data)) {

        $id = "ID:".$row['demo_id']."<br>";
        $name = "Name: ".$row['demo_name']."<br>";
        $version = "Version: ".$row['demo_version']."<br>";
        $details = "Details: ".$row['demo_details']."<br>";
        $file = "File Link: ".$row['file']."<br>";
        $new = basename( $row['file'] ); // GET FILE NAME ONLY, GET RID OF PATH.

        echo "<a href='http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}:8080/demo_webpages_project/images/$new'>";
        echo "<img src='../demo_webpages_project/images/$new'/>";
        echo '</a>';
```

You should not need the port number on this code, or the full domain name, if you do use it, you would have to amend all this code when you move to a real live server, or from one domain to another, which of course you like the rest of us would forget to do.

So try this instead

```
        echo "<a href='demo_webpages_project/images/$new'>";
        echo "<img src='../demo_webpages_project/images/$new'/>";
        echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
        echo '<a href = "http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':8080/demo_webpages_project/images/'.$new.'"> Link </a>';
```